# Axios Config not showing OnUploadPorgress on my repsonse

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have been trying to get the progress from the file uploading from the frontend but in the catch i am not getting the onUploadProgress in the config and it is not working i am new in using axios

```
        axios({

        method: 'post',
        url:'https://brandsaviorservices.azurewebsites.net/api/document/upload/'+this.username+'/1',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token,
        },
        data,config
        }) .then(response => {
            console.log(response);  
            this.status = response.data
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
```

here is my console log

[image: enter code here]

here is my console the file is uploading correctly but not getting the file upload progress using the OnUploadPorgress

[image]

Comment: Currently, you are getting an error with code 400 (server is not able to understand the request). Probably because there is an extra space before .then. First make sure you are able to upload the photo successfully and then you can implement upload progress. Check https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/examples/upload/index.html

Comment: @cdoshi i have add the success response image  you can check but no OnUploadPorgress in config yet

Comment: Where have you defined your config variable?

Comment: thanks but my problem is solved i used the onUploadProgress outside the config and it worked thanks @cdoshi

Comment: glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @cdoshi

I have found the solution and it is working

by doing the OnUploadProgress function out of the config it worked without any error